# Ordering/positioning of floats in document with only and many floats

Tags: floats, positioning

I have a document that only contains of many floats (tables and figures).

Is it possible to force floats to be in the same order in the pdf document as they are in the .tex file?

It is not important where exactly the floats are located as long as they are in the correct order.

Comment: How about inserting tables and figures directly in the document without floating environment? This would ensure that they are in the correct order.

Comment: This is the situation where floats are pretty pointless. If you still need captions, package `capt-of` comes in handy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default latex will keep the order of figures and tables, but in separate classes. So a table can move behind a figure even if it is before in the tex-file. If you want figures and tables to belong to the same class of floats, you should redefine the type of tables:

```
\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
\edef\ftype@table{\ftype@figure} %force the table to stick between the figures
\makeatother
\begin{document}
some text
\begin{figure}
figure 1
\end{figure}

\begin{table}[p] %p for the example ...
table
\end{table}

\begin{figure}
figure 2
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```